# how to integrate salesforce with php in a website?

Tags: rest-api, api, php

I am new to API integration. I have a project where requirement is mostly based on SalesForce Integration.

I need to manage membership form, subscribe form, contact form, event form with SalesForce integration.

I am good at core php but i am not getting how to perform CRUD operation to generate, edit, delete, update lead on submission of individual form.

What i need is the basic working example of SalesForce integration with PHP and How to integrate with REST API.

Please provide the working source of SalesForce Integration with PHP.

Comment: there are already exist force.com php toolkit available it that https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit

Comment: I'd consider using a third party like Auth0 to assist with the authentication piece: https://auth0.com/authenticate/laravel/salesforce/

Answer (score 3):

As @Ratan already said, if you want to use the SOAP API you can go to the [developer pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit).

If you're looking to use the REST API, you can look at this [Salesforce Cookbook](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php) page.

If you're using a PHP Framework, such as Laravel, there is a [Laravel Extension called Forrest.](https://github.com/omniphx/forrest)

Comment: That Salesforce Cookbook page was posted in 2010, do you know if it is still relevant?

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a dated question but I've been tasked with this for a project today, so perhaps I've got some useful notes for someone else coming up to the same situation.

I came across a PHP library to provide you with a SalesForce SOAP client you can make functional calls to:

https://github.com/phpforce/soap-client

This is available via [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) if you're looking for a ready-to-use library not tied to a specific framework:

```
composer require phpforce/common dev-master
composer require phpforce/soap-client dev-master
```

This library is also capable of logging to a PSR-3 compatible logger interface such as the widely used Monolog. -- A nice bonus.

So far this seems like a reputable package considering it only has a `dev-master` checkout (no 1.0 yet), though I'm still quite early into using it.